# Hadoop Scheduling | 2 extremes | Availability and Scarcity of Resources

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have the following 6 Datanodes(dn):

- dn1 - 6 cores 6GB - 3 Map Slots and 3 Reduce Slots
- dn2 - 6 cores 6GB - 3 Map Slots and 3 Reduce Slots
- dn3 - 6 cores 6GB - 3 Map Slots and 3 Reduce Slots
- dn4 - 6 cores 6GB - 3 Map Slots and 3 Reduce Slots
- dn5 - 6 cores 6GB - 3 Map Slots and 3 Reduce Slots
- dn6 - 6 cores 6GB - 3 Map Slots and 3 Reduce Slots

## Case 1 (Availability)

```
State of the system
===================
dn1 has 1 mapper running from another job Y; so 2 mapper slots are free
dn2 has 1 mapper running from another job Y; so 2 mapper slots are free
dn3 has 1 mapper running from another job Y; so 2 mapper slots are free
dn4 has 1 mapper running from another job Y; so 2 mapper slots are free
dn5 has 0 mappers running; so 3 mapper slots are free
dn6 has 0 mappers running; so 3 mapper slots are free
State of my input file
======================
I have a file that is distributed in 3 64MB blocks with RF 3 in the following way: 
R1(dn1,dn2,dn3) 
R2(dn2,dn3,dn4) 
R3(dn3,dn4,dn5)
```

When I run a job X on this file, 3 mappers need to be created corresponding to the 3 data blocks.

### Questions

```
In FIFO: Is Job X still put on the queue waiting for Y to finish considering its a FIFO scheduler and other jobs are running even though "there are other mapper slots free in the same machine" or the FIFO logic kicks in only when no more resources are available in the system and the jobs consequently has to be put on the queue?
In Capacity Scheduler: What would the behavior be?
In Fair Share Scheduler: What would the behavior be?
```

## Case 2 (Scarcity)

```
State of the system
===================
dn1 has 3 mappers running from another job Y; so 0 mapper slots are free
dn2 has 3 mappers running from another job Y; so 0 mapper slots are free
dn3 has 3 mappers running from another job Y; so 0 mapper slots are free
dn4 has 3 mappers running from another job Y; so 0 mapper slots are free
dn5 has 3 mappers running from another job Y; so 0 mapper slots are free
dn6 has 0 mappers running; so 3 mapper slots are free
```

I have a file that is distributed in 3 64MB blocks with RF 3 in the following way:

```
R1(dn1,dn2,dn3) 
R2(dn2,dn3,dn4) 
R3(dn3,dn4,dn5)
```

When I run a job X on this file, 3 mappers need to be created corresponding to the 3 data blocks.

### Questions

What happens now:

```
    - Are the 3 mapper tasks created on dn6 (which does not have any of the data blocks of the input file yet) and corresponding data block transferred over the network from say dn1 to dn6?
        - If yes, does this same behaviour show in the case of all the three schedulers: FIFO/Capacity/Fair Share?
            - If no, then can you elaborate on the behaviour shown for this use case in case of:
                - FIFO Scheduler
                - Capacity Scheduler
                - Fair Share Scheduler
```

Comment: Datanodes don't control job placement. The Nodemanagers do. 6G on the machines also doesn't mean you can allocate 6G worth of MapReduce containers on them

Comment: @cricket_007 I completely understand; I was using the term dn loosely for the slave machines. And yes, I agree 6G on the machines does not really translate to 6 containers...as you have other daemons running as well like DN, NM, AM etc....what I meant here was "6G 6 cores available for MR". If we abstract out the 6G and 6 core part, and just say that each machine has 3 Mapper and 3 Reducer Slots, then how do the schedulers behave in the 2 cases above?

Comment: Well, FIFO is the easiest - it waits for jobs to complete before continuing. Capacity will perform bin-packing, and Fair will preempt/pause/kill other jobs, I believe

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. There are 2 cases. In the first case, there are enough mapper slots free in dn1 to dn4 (read slave 1 to slave 4) despite job Y running; are you saying FIFO still does not schedule the new job X? In the second case, irrespective of the scheduling type, there are no mapper slots available in dn1 to dn5. dn6 is free. But dn6 does not have the data blocks required for job X. Can't the job be scheduled  to run on this free slave dn6 now and have data blocks/input splits from the relevant  slave nodes be transferred over the network into the memory of the mapper tasks in dn6?

Comment: Are we assuming that all "slots" require the same amount of memory to be put into them? And the input data is also consistently sized? I think FIFO packs in until no more resources left, then others are waiting. For the others, Capacity and Fair allow individual queues to used to set percentage of memory aside. Bursting workload queues are allowed to take resources away from the others, so it's not just based on single "slots" of any one node, rather all available slots of the whole cluster, for a given queue

Comment: Yes, for the purposes of the concept...thanks for the inputs!